# NoClassDefFoundError running HashMap definition in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, hashmap, noclassdeffounderror

I have wanted to use a HashMap that maps a value of type String using a key of type Integer. This is the definition:

```
HashMap <String, Integer> dict = new HashMap <String,Integer>();
```

I don't get any compiling errors. However, when I am debugging I get the error bellow when running that line:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String myProject.client.ProjectService.state(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/util/collect/HashMap
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at ................
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your import statements. Make sure you are importing "java.util.HashMap".

(I think you imported "com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashMap" )